# All words in a trie data-structure

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, trie

I'm trying to put all words in a trie in a string, a word is denoted by the `eow` field being true for a certain character in the trie data structure, hence a trie can could have letters than lead up to no word, for ex "abc" is in the trie but "c"'s eow field is false so "abc" is not a word

Here is my Data structure

```
struct Trie {

  bool eow; //when a Trie field isWord = true, hence there is a word
  char letter;
  Trie *letters[27];

};
```

and here is my attemped print-all function, basically trying to return all words in one string seperated by spaces for words

```
string printAll( string word, Trie& data)
{
  if (data.eow == 1)
    return word + " ";
  for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    if (data.letters[i] != NULL)
     printAll( word + data.letters[i]->letter, *(data.letters[i]));
 }
  return "";
}
```

Its not outputting what i want, any suggestions?

Comment: I do not think "detonate" is the word you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the return value of your recursive `printAll()` call, so all the sub-words you generate are lost. Try something like this:

```
string printAll(string word, const Trie& data)
{
  string words;

  if (data.eow)
    words += word + " ";
  for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    if (data.letters[i] != NULL)
     words += printAll( word + data.letters[i]->letter, *(data.letters[i]));
  }
  return words;
}
```

For what it's worth, this is a bit inefficient in that it allocates lots of temporary strings. Each recursive call has its own `words` string which is built up, returned, and destroyed. It'd be better to add all the words to one string.

Also you might consider using a vector of words rather than adding them together with spaces. That way you can more easily iterate over each word.

```
void getWords(const Trie& data, vector<string> &words, string word = "")
{
  if (data.eow)
    words.push_back(word);

  for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    if (data.letters[i] != NULL)
      getWords(*(data.letters[i]), words, word + data.letters[i]->letter);
  }
}
```

Then to call it:

```
vector<string> words;
getWords(trie, words);

for (size_t i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i) {
  if (i > 0)
    cout << " ";

  cout << words[i];
}

cout << endl;
```

Comment: -John Kugelman -what if i had a prefix as input and wanted to print only words from that prefix onwards? .. I'm thinking of setting a pointer to the last letter of the prefix, but i find it hard since my printall function will print words before the prefix since those are also words? Any ideas?